# Work around using custom image as default video thumb?

Tags: youtube, embed, customization, thumb

After uploading a new video in YouTube, three thumbnail images are generated automatically by YouTube. Unfortunately, these three images are often useless. Is there any workaround to use my own custom thumbnail image when using the embed code?

Comment: I found JW Player the best option as the workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out within Wordpress and Wordpress Plugins. I just used the Wordpress lightbox plus plugin that allows you to choose what image to display and it has a embed video feature. There is also a way to customize the Wordpress Template, but I went for the easy route.